# In selection, can the focusOffset be before the anchorOffset?

Tags: javascript, html, selection, range

In programmatically defining a range/selection in JavaScript, is it not possible to have the focusOffset in the range be before the anchorOffset? How do we define a right to left selection then?

a JS fiddler link for example: http://jsfiddle.net/johncch/ejVab/1/

Comment: in the makeselection check the a > b and if its true, reverse them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there no way to create a reversed (i.e. right-to-left) selection from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801464/is-there-no-way-to-create-a-reversed-i-e-right-to-left-selection-from-javascr)

Comment: You are right. It is a duplicate. Sorry for the weak Search-fu!

Comment: Don't worry, I just knew I'd answered this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to create a "backwards" selection is slightly non-obvious. It can't be done by simply selecting a Range via the selection `addRange()` method because ranges are intrinsically directionless. You need to use the [`extend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/extend) method of the selection (example below).

Note this doesn't work in any version of IE, including 9: unlike previous versions, IE 9 does have standard selection and range objects but at the time Microsoft was developing IE 9, `extend()` was non-standard so they didn't implement it, meaning that there is no way to create a backwards selection programmatically in any version of IE yet released. IE 10 did not implement `extend()`, despite my filing a [bug on the IE bug tracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/737106/implement-missing-extend-method-of-selection).

```
function selectRangeBackwards(range) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var endRange = range.cloneRange();
    endRange.collapse(false);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(endRange);
    sel.extend(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
}
```

Comment: Immensely interesting. I'm almost convinced that it is not worth the effort to hijack browser behavior. It does make coding around browser behavior messy though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap two variables then:

```
function makeSelection(a, b) {
    if(b < a) {
        var tmpA = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmpA;
    }
    // ... rest of your code
```

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejVab/2/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) is a good MDN doc on the selection. The anchorOffset/anchorNode denotes the "start" of the selection (where it was started, say, during a mouse drag), while focusOffset/focusNode denotes the "end" of the selection (where the user finished the drag). This is of little use for determining the left/right ends of a selection. To detect them, you need the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) object - use startContainer/startOffset for the left selection boundary, and endContainer/endOffset for the right boundary. Get the range from your selection as

```
if (window.getSelection() && window.getSelection().rangeCount)
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

Guess this is enough to build the right selection.

Comment: This is all good but not quite enough to create a backwards selection.