# How to save and restore anchorNode/anchorOffset & focusNode/focusOffset?

Tags: javascript, range, getselection, addrange

In the following code:

```
var s=window.getSelection();
var sr=s.getRangeAt(0);

console.log(s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset);

s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(sr);

console.log(s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset);
```

The anchorOffset and focusOffset are swapped when replacing a range.  i.e. The anchor resets to the leftmost end of the selection and the focus to the rightmost, regardless of from which end the selection actually started and ended.  It seems the anchor and focus are ignored when adding a range (or at least not stored), and it defaults and assumes left anchor and right focus.

This is a damn nuisance!

I don't hold out much hope, but is there any way I'm missing that I can work around this behavior.  I would really love to be able to restore the original anchor and focus positions.

Works same in chrome and firefox.

**EDIT**

Ok have worked out a partial answer:

```
var s=window.getSelection();
var sr=s.getRangeAt(0);

console.log(s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset);

var aN=s.anchorNode,aO=s.anchorOffset,fN=s.focusNode,fO=s.focusOffset;

s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(sr);

s.collapse(aN,aO);
s.extend(fN,fO);

console.log(s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset);
```

HOWEVER, this won't work in IE9+ as IE doesn't implement the extend method.  So now the question becomes, how to make IE play nice in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's just impossible in IE. I raised a [bug in the IE bug tracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/737106/implement-missing-extend-method-of-selection) a year ago suggesting they implement `extend()` but it hasn't happened and now they've closed the bug it seems unlikely to happen any time soon.

**UPDATE: The IE bug has been reopened so there is hope.**

Here are my answers to two similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802994/96100
- [In selection, can the focusOffset be before the anchorOffset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705569/in-selection-can-the-focusoffset-be-before-the-anchoroffset)

Comment: Looks like your persistence is paying off @TimDown. The bug is "active" and received a comment from Ben Peters who is quite active on the W3C mailing lists.

Comment: @teleclimber: That was a direct result of my whinging about it to him off-list when the subject came up on the W3C mailing list :)